# Get Firestore subcollections

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with getting data from the **Firestore** with a following structure:

[image: Firestore structure]

Here is how I get category collection:

```
var defaultStore: Firestore?
var location: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    defaultStore = Firestore.firestore()

    defaultStore?.collection("Category").getDocuments { (querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot?, error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.location = (querySnapshot?.documents)!
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It gives me: `Books`, `Films`, `From test` and `Serials`.
But how can I get collections from `Films` for example?

Comment: you can just use another collection call. defaultStore?.collection("Category").collection("Foo").getDocuments()

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla , It's give me error `Value of type 'CollectionReference' has no member 'collection'`

Comment: Yes. Sorry I forgot to add the document after the first collection

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can try

```
defaultStore?.collection("Category").document("Film").collection("firstFilm").getDocuments();
```

Because Films, Books etc are documents not collections as you can see. For more info read here [Firestore data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model)

Comment: also, we can use fhttps://firebaseopensource.com/projects/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/docs/ktx/firestore.md/

Comment: This is really hard when it's come to using random id,  You cannot simply get the collection of it's subcollection in method like the above. You need to loop it get it. But at final hard to implement.