# Swift Firebase setting data error, cannot add .collection to query

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set data in my Firestore database. I want to find a document in a collection using the where method and then navigates to its sub collection and set data. I think I'm getting an error because the where the method returns a query that doesn't have a .collection. Does anyone know how I can reformat this code so it performs such an action?

```
let placeHolder = ["place": ""]
let document = Firestore.firestore().collection("tweets").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid).collection("comments").document("hello")

document.setData(placeHolder)
```

Comment: You will have to execute the query, read the results, then perform more queries using the document(s) you found.  It's not just a simple change.

Comment: @DougStevenson can you show me an example possibly

Comment: [check this question out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52311222/14745547) I hope it helps

Comment: @jackmanAhmed Have you checked the above comment by Hidayet is that helpful?

Comment: In the official Firestore documentation, you will find very simple examples of how to query for documents using the where operator. You will also find very simple examples of how to write to documents (including in subcollections). Just perform one after the other in your code, it's that simple.